# How to pass postgre sql schema in Python Dataset

Tags: python, postgresql, dataset

I have a code to insert row:

```
try:       
    con = dataset.connect("postgresql://abc:abc@localhost:5432/dbname") 
    con.begin()  
    result = con.load_table("schema1.table_name").insert(document)  
    con.commit()          
    return result
except Exception as e:    
    return False
```

But I always get the error like this:

> raise DatasetException("Table does not exist: %s" % self.name)

It's the issue related to schema, how can I pass schema name into this insert query?

Comment: `result = con.load_table("schema1.{}".format(table_name)` where `table_name` is your variable. There is no way to use SQL parameterization for table names, and im unusure whether `load_table` is vulnerable to injection (I don't think so)

Comment: @riganjosh: result = con.load_table("schema1.{}".format(table_name)).insert(document)  doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Cool, are you going to give me any indication why, so that I might understand and try a different approach, or just tell me that it doesn't work?

Comment: hello riganjosh, it shows me the same error(table not exists). i think format(table_name) is not so different with my code.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who need:

con = dataset.connect("postgresql://abc:abc@localhost:5432/dbname", schema=schema)